# eclipse slash in vm argument

Tags: eclipse, jvm-arguments, slash

I have the same code running on Java 6 and Java 7, but in Java 7 it doesn't work as I expect.

I write in the VM argument:

```
-Dmy.root=D:\mvobs\S.4.8.600_view\
```

When I run it with Java 6 everything is OK:

```
my.root=[D:\mvobs\S.4.8.600_view\\]
```

but in Java 7 I got:

```
my.root=[D:\mvobs\S.4.8.600_view]
```

where does the last slash gone?

I also moved form eclipse 3.4.0 to Juno (in order to work with Java 7)

what can be the problem?

Comment: Why are there two `\\` in the Java 6 version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where it went but you probably shouldn't rely on it anyway.

To build paths, use `new File(String, String)` or `new File(File, String)` because these methods get it right on every OS. So to open a file relative to `my.root`:

```
File myRoot = new File( System.getProperty( "my.root" ) );
File file = new File( myRoot, "filename" );
```

Comment: In the code I concat it with additional path. It use to wrok but now I need to change the code before concat and to add the slash in the code. I want the same code to work in java 6 and java 7. If in the vm argument i write / everthing works fine in both java 6 & 7.

Comment: @user2042494: Create more `File` objects to build the path. Tedious but safe.

Comment: Something which parses the VM arguments might think that \ is an escape character. That's why `/` works better.